# dynamic wpf uniformgrid column count

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, uniformgrid

I am trying to build a dynamic uniformgrid in wpf which will change the number of columns based on the width of the control. So essentially if the application is full screen then show 7 columns, if the application is resized to be a small width then only 1 column must show. I want to accommodate those really wide screen sizes and if the user wants to tuck the app off to the side of the screen.

I am displaying a card view of data, which in this case is some generic employee data with a portrait image.

My initial thought on how to solve this was to link up the width property of the uniformgrid to the viewmodel and bind the column count to another property where the get would be a function to calculate the column count. But this didn't work because the bindings don't work that way with the size property, even with OneWayToSource mode.

the solution I have found so far is to create a custom UniformGrid class and override the MeasuerOverride method. It works except that it runs every time the screen size is changed, which makes the application slow. And that it isn't triggered when you maximize the screen, or pin it to the side of the screen.

```
public class EmployeeUniformGrid : UniformGrid
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size size = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        if (size.Width > 1200) this.Columns = 7;
        if (size.Width > 400) this.Columns = 2;
        return size;
    }
}
```

So the real question here is, how is this kind of functionality achieved using MVVM (if possible) and made in such a way that it doesnt slow down the application so much?

Comment: Why not simply using `WrapPanel`? Make sure all cell elements are of the same size and the rest is automatic.

Comment: Do not set the Columns property in MeasureOverride. Better override OnRenderSizeChanged. Even better, use a WrapPanel.

Comment: The reason that I chose to not use a WrapPanel was so that I can get the EmployeeCard to resize based on the users screen size, although the WrapPanel does do exactly what I want it to do, given that the Cards can now be made dynamic somehow.